# ngbTypeAhead never shows suggestions

Tags: angular, autocomplete, ng-bootstrap

I have found a very odd behaviour with `ng-boostrap` for an App I am developing.

I am using `ng-bootstrap: 1.1.x` with **Angular 5.2.x**

#### `component.html`

has the `bootstrap 4-alpha` card. (code reduced for brewity)

```
<div class="card-block">
                        <label for="typeahead-template"><span>Search</span></label>
                        <input id="typeahead-template"
                               type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               [(ngModel)]="searchModel"
                               [ngbTypeahead]="search"
                               [resultTemplate]="rt"
                               [inputFormatter]="formatter"
                        >
                        <ng-template #rt let-r="result" let-t="term">
                            {{ r.translatedProperty}}
                        </ng-template>
                    <select size="10" class="form-control mr-4">
                        <optgroup label="Properties">
                            <option *ngFor="let eachVal of dataResults">
                                {{eachVal.translatedProperty}}
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
                        <optgroup label="References">
                            <option *ngFor="let eachVal of objResults">
                                {{eachVal.translatedProperty}}
                            </option>
                        </optgroup>
                    </select>
</div>
```

The output looks like below:

[image: Card Image]

#### `component.ts`

`this.propertyResults` is an empty array of type `any` defined as `public` where response from server is stored.

```
 // Autocompletion Implementation from NG-BOOTSTRAP
    public search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
        text$.pipe(
            debounceTime(200),
            map((term: string) => term === '' ? []
                : this.propertyResults.filter(v => v.translatedProperty.toLowerCase()
                    .indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1).slice(0, 10))
    );
    public formatter = (x: {translatedProperty: string}) => x.translatedProperty;
```

### working

The backend is called and the information is stored in `this.propertyResults` array and then user proceeds to search something in the `input` field, hence triggering `search` for the Typeahead.

#### data

data from server looks like:

```
[
  {
    "propertyURL": "http://semanticweb.org/blahblah",
    "datatypeProperty": true,
    "objectProperty": false,
    "translatedProperty": "AverageDeliveryTimeInDays"
  },
  .. so on
]
```

## Current Output

No suggestions displayed from `ng-template`
[image: No suggestion]

**NOTE**: on the contrary, when I press <kbd>Tab</kbd> key I get the suggestion filled! How is that? I have a [StackBlitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-workflow-test) for the same and there is works perfectly. But on using the same code in the Application I cannot see suggestions.

Has this something to do with the layout within the card? I need the suggestion template to showup as it is critical for the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the component works well with **Bootstrap 4.1.1** and the previous version that I was using was **Bootstap 4-alphav3** which might have caused problems.